# How to cross-link two sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large sheet `A` from which I only want to work with a subset of columns sorted in a different order in a sheet `B`. I can import data dynamically from `A` to `B` with `={Data!S:S}` (for column `S`). However I would like the data to be imported the other way around too.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 uh. I can't do that. I just want a second sheet just like the first one. But without some of the columns. And when I edit either one of those - the other should update automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would create an infinite **circular dependency** paradox. google sheets does not work like this. only one of your two sheets can be dependant on the other one. so if sheet A is your full dataset and sheet B is "extraction of certain columns from your sheet A dataset", then if you edit your sheet A your sheet B will instantly reflect those changes. the other way around would break the formula and it would introduce mentioned circular dependency